# What is the xpath of gmail password field in firefox browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate gmail in firefox browser using selenium webdriver and firebug.

Selenium is not identify the xpath of the password fileld.

what is the xpath of the password field.

Comment: Which one you've tried?

Comment: Firebug is outdated. I use chrome to get xpaths etc. which works fine.

Comment: //input[contains(@aria-label,'Enter your password')][@autocomplete='current-password'] use this

Comment: How to get xpath in chrome

Comment: use  xpath helper

Answer (score 1):

While you try to log into your *Gmail Account*, on filling up the *EmailID/Phone* field with text and simultaneously click on the <kbd>Next</kbd> button, the text field for **Password** takes a delta amount of time to be clickable/interactable within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). Hence apart from just locating the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) for **Password** field you have to induce some **Explicit Wait** i.e. **WebDriverWait** as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")));
password.sendKeys("your_password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below mentioned xpath:

```
//*[@name="password"]
```

I suggest you to verify the xpath on Console of Chrome Browser.
If your application supports Chrome with below mentioned syntax

```
$x("//*[@name='password']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath :

```
By.xpath(.//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input)
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: what is the error you are getting.You may be facing some synchronization issue.Try using wait

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath:

```
 //INPUT[@type='password']
```

Try this one. firebug is outdated I would suggest you use other softwares for more complex xpaths.

Comment: which software i use for xpath

Comment: I am using relative xpath helper and xpath helper. Both are very reliable but mostly i use the first one, the second one is when things get tough and xpath becomes very very complicated. Please mark answer as accepted if it worked for you.

Comment: What is relative xpath helper & xpath helper

Comment: Add-ons on google chrome that provide you with relative and absolute xpath.

Comment: I used this one. But it only works if you add Thread.sleep(1000); before sendKey

Comment: That means that your field password is not there when you run your xpath line, so by using sleep you give your code "time" to create it and then parse it with the xpath. This happens when elements appear after an action so your code moves too fast in your xpath line and tries to locate your element but it is not there yet. Sleep is a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
//input[@type='password']
```

else you can locate like

```
driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any of below XPath

```
//input[@type='password']
```

OR

```
//input[@name='password']
```

OR

```
//input[contains(@aria-label,'Enter your password')]
```

OR

```
//input[contains(@autocomplete,'current-password')]
```

The complete code will like below :-

```
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Next')]")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("123456");
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
     WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Next')]")));
     element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

use this xpaths

```
//input[@class='whsOnd zHQkBf'][@name='password']
//input[@type='password']
//*[@type='password']
//input[contains(@aria-label,'Enter your password')][@name='password']
//input[contains(@aria-label,'Enter your password')][@autocomplete='current-password']
```

Instead of using `xpath` you should use `name` as  it have priority over `xpath` like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\software and tools\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver   chrome_driver = new ChromeDriver();
chrome_driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");
```

or you can use any xpath

```
chrome_driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath you want")).sendKeys("xxxxxxxxxx");
```

Comment: Follow this link to learn more :http://learn-automation.com/xpath-checker-for-chrome-browser/