# unable to locate the password field in gmail .getting the error "webdriver exception"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.testng.annotations.*;
    import static org.testng.Assert.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class Withtestng {
      private WebDriver driver;

      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/bin/geckodriver");
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/bin/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }

      @Test
      public void testGmailLogInHtml() throws Exception {
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/nav/div/a[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("xyz@gmail.com");


 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']/content")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='whsOnd zHQkBf']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='whsOnd zHQkBf']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='whsOndzHQkBf']")).sendKeys("xyz");***
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='passwordNext']/content/span"))click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='gb']/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/a/span")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("gb_71")).click();
          }
```

Comment: Please post the complete Stacktrace.

Comment: <input class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-password" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your password" name="password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" data-initial-value="" style="" xpath="1" type="password">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the xpath of gmail password field in firefox browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112799/what-is-the-xpath-of-gmail-password-field-in-firefox-browser)

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <input type="email" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="username" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Email or phone" name="identifier" autocapitalize="none" id="identifierId" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="xyz" badinput="false"> is not clickable at point (451, 427). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ANuIbb IdAqtf" jsname="k4HEge" tabindex="0"></div>

Comment: (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.13.0-43-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'

Comment: @suvenduacharya Your `chromedriver=2.35` and `chrome=66.0` is out of sync. Upgrade to `chromedriver=2.38`

Answer (score 0):

Your script execution speed and page load time is not in sync, try to use 
pageLoadTimeout.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//
```

Or

You can wait for particular condition becomes true(ie. wait until element present using wait.until) and then perform operation on it.